# .Net SOAP encoding my XML message

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, soap

I am trying to send a request to a web service. It is set up as a service reference in my visual studio console app. The service requires a XML string as it's parameter. When I send the string, it is encoding my XML tags with &gt and &lt. They tell me this won't work for them. How can I change this? Is there anyway around this?

Here is what some of the SOAP message is showing:

```
<Orders xsi:type="xsd:string">
    &lt;?xml version="1.0"?&gt;&lt;
```

Comment: You'll have to tell us the definition of the parameter that's causing the problem. If it's defined as being a string, then .NET is doing the right thing.

Comment: I meant for you to show the relevant definitions from the WSDL. However, this does look like the service is presenting `Orders` as being of type "xsd:string". This means that Visual .NET has done the right thing. If they want `Orders` to contain arbitrary XML, then they need to use the type `xsd:any`, or else define an custom `complexType` and use that.

Answer (score 1):

What technology is used to develop the web service?

In .NET when passing an XML parameter as string the .NET framework encodes it on the client and decodes it back on the server which is absolutely correct.

If the web service is developed in someother technology i guess they need to perform a decode on the string to convert it back to an Xml string.

Comment: -1: that's not the situation. Please read the question again.